# jquery values not sent to javascript function

Tags: jquery, websocket

I have a websocket connection which send json values constantly and this is in js file

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
    if (!msg || !msg.data) {
        return;
    }
    var json = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    if (document.getElementById(json.name)) {
        document.getElementById(json.name).innerHTML = json.value;
    }
}

function myDelay(rm) {
    var speed = $('#rmval).val();
    console.log(speed);
}
```

In my html file I have the following

```
<table id="valTable">
    <tr>
        <td Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="rmval"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>myDelay($("#rmval").val());</script>
```

However in the console I see a null value in the myDelay function even though the value of the field is displayed on the web page ( id="rmval">)
Please help

Comment: call function inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: i tried doing this. however it still does not work

Comment: Did you try `$("#rmval").text()`/`$("#rmval").html()`? `td` doesn't have value.